# What is the proper way to create a php database connection with PDO?

Tags: php, database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

## Background

I have recently been put in charge of maintaining an almost completed website and backend that is written in 6 or so languages (HTML, javascript, php, java, postgres, python...). I'm good with some of these, but not others (php, javascript).

## The Problem

I can't connect the website to the postgres database with php. I've found and modified a file called dbconn.php (which presumably is responsible for connecting to the database) and it looks like this currently:

```
<?php
    $host = "redshift-cluster-merp.something.region.redshift.amazonaws.com";
    $port = 5430;
    $user = "awsuser";
    $pass = "myfancypassword";
    $dbName = "merpdev";

    $dsn = "pgsql:host=$host;dbname=$dbName;port=$port;";
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
?>
```

This doesn't create a connection between the website and database. However, I am able to log into the database from the same ip address in terminal via

psql -h redshift-cluster-merp.something.region.redshift.amazonaws.com -U awsuser -p 5430 -d merpdev

And I can also connect via JDBC with similar parameters. Is the file `dbconn.php` correct or am I missing something?

I imagine the lines with `$dsn` and/or `$pdo` might have a syntactic error.

Comment: `try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}` lets see some errors

Comment: not certain you need the last semi-colon in your dsn string.

Comment: @tim I put these into php console and tried  `echo $e` and got an `Undefined variable` error. Does that mean that the connection worked? thanks!

Comment: if you echo $e outside of the catch it wont be defined, if you got no error from the catch, then perhaps the connection is working, but your post says its not, so i'm confused.

Comment: @tim good to know. I assumed the connection was the problem as there is no data on any of the pages of this website. I'll dig a bit further and see what I can find.